# A detail in Evans's prove of THEOREM 3 in section 6.5 (about principal eigenvalue)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations

The following picture shows the statement of the theorem and the first part of Evans' proof.
[image]
In his prove, Evans defines an operater A, which I know is properly defined (because of the maximum principle) and is linear on X, but what I don't understand is why A is compact. At first I thought it should use compact embedding like in section 6.2, but seems it's not the case, and I don't know what is the norm of space X as the intersection of two banach space. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Definitely it's the compact embedding. Did you try to prove it directly (assume that you have a bounded sequence $\{f_n\}$, you need to show $\{Af_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence)

Comment: A bounded sequence $(f_n)$ in $X$ should be bounded in some Hölder space (using Sobolev inequalities) and thus by Arzelà-Ascoli you have a uniformly convergent subsequence. I'd try to build a convergent subsequence of $(Af_n)$ from that. In fact, you have two derivatives to spare, thus, you can get a convergent subsequence (again by Arzelà-Ascoli) in $C^2(\overline{U})$, which should allow you to find a convergent subsequence of $(Af_n)$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I think I have figured it out, I have posted my proof below.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that I have ignored the simple fact that $X=H^m(U)\cap H_0^1(U)$ is a closed subspace of $H^m(U)$: for a sequence $\{f_n\}\subset X$ converge to $f$ in $H^m(U)$, $\{f_n\}$ also converge in $H^1(U)$ and since $H_0^1(U)$ is a closed subspace of $H^1(U)$, $f\in X$. So the norm of X should be $H^m(U)$-norm.

Now we proof $A$ is compact. Let $\{f_n\}\subset X$ be a bounded sequance. Use the estimate in Thoerem 5 of section 6.3, we have
$$
\Vert Af_n\Vert_{H^{m+2}(U)}\leq C_1(\Vert f_n\Vert_{H^{m}(U)}+\Vert Af_n\Vert_{L^2(U)})
$$
Moreover, by the theorem "boundness of inverse" in section 6.2, we have $\Vert Af_n\Vert_{L^2(U)}\leq C\Vert f_n\Vert_{L^2(U)}$ for some constant $C$. So we can deduce $\{Af_n\}$ is bounded in
$H^{m+2}(U)$, what left is to show that a bounded sequence in $H^{m+2}(U)$ has subsequence converge in $H^m(U)$.

To prove this statement, we apply induction to $m$. Suppose the conclusion is true for natural number $k$ not larger than m. For $k=m+1$, Let $\{f_n\}\subset X$ be a bounded sequence in $H^{k+2}(U)=H^{m+3}(U)$, then by induction hypothesis, $\{f_n\}$ has subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ converge in $H^m(U)$. For $\alpha$ satisfy $|\alpha|=m+1$, $\{D^{\alpha}f_{n_k}\}\subset H^2(U)\subset H^1(U)$ is bounded, since $H^1(U)$ can be compactly embedded in $L^2(U)$, we know $\{D^{\alpha}f_{n_k}\}$ converge in $L^2(U)$. Then $\{f_{n_k}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $H^{m+1}(U)$ and we have proved the conclusion for $k
= m+1$. $\square$